# How to use preg_split to split string at whitespace between numbers?

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I have been trying to create a regex expression which only selects the whitespace between numbers, which preg_split can split.

For example:

```
$string = "Unit 54 981 Mayne Street";
```

Would return as:

```
array() { 
  [0]=> "Unit 54" 
  [1]=> "981 Mayne Street" 
}
```

I have had no luck so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look into lookahead & behinds: as they are officially not part of the match, they will be preserved, and only the whitespace is removed in the splitting.

Comment: Thank you! That is what I was trying but I must have missed something in my attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [lookaround assertions](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php), like this:

```
$result = preg_split('/(?<=\d)\s+(?=\d)/', $string);
```

This will match any sequence of one or more whitespace characters that are immediately preceded and followed by a digit character. It produces this array:

```
Array (
    [0] => "Unit 54"
    [1] => "981 Mayne Street"
)
```

Comment: Thank you! That solves my problem exactly. My regex was so close, but fatally flawed. Apparently I have to wait seven minutes to be able to accept your answer.

Comment: @Sam- Glad I could help. In the future though, make sure you include your attempts in the question. You'll get better results, and we can tell you where you went wrong.

Comment: Thanks, next time I will.